# Can't install snaps: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, software-installation, snap

Recently, I upgrade my 18.04 laptop to 20.04 and during the process it complained that it cannot connect to api.snapcraft.io. I thought this might be fixed after the upgrade but it wasn't. So, I started debugging snap and enabled debug mode in `snap` and run:

```
sudo journalctl -f -u snapd
```

the result is [this](https://pastebin.com/7gZsGrF9).

when I run:

```
sudo snap install notes
```

result:

```
2021/06/26 16:35:20.197787 tool_linux.go:204: DEBUG: restarting into "/snap/snapd/current/usr/bin/snap"
2021/06/26 16:35:40.645576 error.go:102: DEBUG: error: cannot install "notes": Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: no such host
error: cannot install "notes": Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup
       api.snapcraft.io: no such host
```

Based on the `journalctl` output I understand there is problem with a certificate but don't know how to fix it. Googling didn't help either.

EDIT 1:

I managed to fix it on my desktop computer by setting manually the DNS servers to use Google's DNS; however, on my laptop that doesn't work. Furthermore, when I edit the connection details and save them and then go to check them again they are back to the way it was before. Very strange. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you attached the right log output? It does not mention certificates

Comment: @RayWu the pastebin has this at the end: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Comment: @RayWu I've added some more info. It is now fixed on my desktop computer but I still have problems with my laptop.

Comment: What's the date on your device?

Comment: It is the correct date and time.

Comment: this could be an issue with some firewall doing SSL inspection....